# Spivak chapter 5 problem 5 solution explanation

Tags: calculus, limits

> Decide for which numbers $a$ the limit $\lim_{x \to a} f(x)$ exists

where $f(x)$ here is defined by

$f(x) = $ the number obtained by replacing all digits in the decimal expansion of x which comes after the first 7 (if any) by $0$

Graph of the function provided by the solution manual:
[image]

The solution manual says the limit exists for $a$ whose decimal expansion does not end in $7999...$
I get why the limit doesn't exist at those $a$ but shouldn't it not exist for $a$ whose decimal expansion ends in $7000...$ as well?

Comment: Consider $~x_1 = 0.799995, ~$ and $~x_2 = 0.7000005.~$ $x_1~$ and $~x_2~$ are both converted to $0.70.$  Now consider $~y_1 = 0.800005, ~$ and $~y_2 = 0.699995.~$.  $y_1, y_2$ are not changed at all.  $y_1,x_1$ are in the same neighborhood, as are $y_2,x_2$.  After the conversion, $y_1,x_1$ are in different neighborhoods, while $y_2,x_2$ remain in the same neighborhood.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Edit: See comment from user2661923, whose explanation is shorter and probably clearer than mine!

Take the number $0.7$.

(Using Spivak's convention we write this as $0.6999\dots$)

$$f(0.6999\dots) = 0.6999\dots = 0.7$$

Now, what is the value of $f$ just to the right of this number?

$f$ remains constant. It's value is $0.7$ as $x$ increases, up to and including the number $x = 0.799\dots$ (aka $8$).

$$\lim_{x\to 0.7^+} = 0.7$$

What about the left-sided limit?

What happens if we restrict $x$ to be between $0.69$ and $0.7$?

$f$ will be at least $0.69$.

What if we restrict $x$ to be between $0.699$ and $0.7$?

$f$ will be at least $0.699$.

On the left hand side, as we restrict $x$ to be closer and closer to $0.7$, we force $f$ to be closer and closer to $0.7$.

$$\lim_{x\to 0.7^-} = 0.7$$

Both the left-hand and right-hand limits exist and agree.